# Automount swap script

Tags: awk, grep

Trying to create a script which is checking if swap is mounted with cat /proc/meminfo, if output is greather than 0, log a message: Swap already mounted, if not execute a command: swapon /swap

```
#!/bin/sh

if cat /proc/meminfo | grep SwapTotal | awk '{print $2}' = 0
then
swapon /swap
else
echo Swap already mounted
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this command -

```
awk '/SwapTotal/ {if($2==0) {system("swapon /swap")} else print "Swap already mounted"}' /proc/meminfo
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
if [[ -z $(awk '/SwapTotal/{print $2}' /proc/meminfo)  ]]
then
    swapon /swap
else
    echo Swap already mounted
fi
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional [context](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. It also doesn't hurt to mention why this answer is more appropriate than others.